# Grub rescue cannot boot from flashdrive

Tags: dual-boot, grub

yesterday I accidentaly delete some linux partition, before I realize that i deleted some grub config files too...

I run linux, now it shows Welcome to grub rescue.

When i `ls` it shows `(hd0)  (hd0,gpt1)  (hd0,gpt2)` etc.

When i `ls [partition]` shows somthing like `Unknown filesystem.`

`set root=[partition]` and then insmod normal shows `no such partition.`

I searched for some solutions, but none of them worked...

The worst part is that i cannot go to boot menu and change the boot order, so I CANT BOOT FROM FLASHDRIVE...

Any help welcome.

And sorry for my English.

Comment: Try Cold boot to get into UEFI or BIOS, remove battery or fwsetup, & force full system reconfig for hardware changes
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8 Then see if you can boot live installer on USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment yet I have to do it this way. The `ls -l` comment gives you all disks and partitions with their UUID's. 
Why can't you enter the UEFI? Usually there is a Fsomething key to enter it. I can search which key it is if I know what motherboard/laptop you are using.
If you have the possibility to use another computer you can make a flashdrive with Ventoy and put some rescue-iso's ( e.g. Ikki-boot/AiO-SRT/gparted-live/Rescatux/ubuntu-rescue-remix ) and try to recover the lost partition. Remember to write to another disk to avoid overwriting.